# How to remove subsequent duplicate values in Python?

Tags: python, partitioning

I have a df that looks like the following:

```
event_name   |user_id|time_event             |time_install
ProfileScreen|1111   |2021-05-01 11:31:00.679|2021-05-01 11:31:00.679
ProfileScreen|1111   |2021-05-01 11:35:22.273|2021-05-01 11:31:00.679 <--- Delete
WalletScreen |1111   |2021-05-01 11:37:00.329|2021-05-01 11:31:00.679
ProfileScreen|1111   |2021-05-01 11:38:24.456|2021-05-01 11:31:00.679
HomeScreen   |1111   |2021-05-01 11:38:00.679|2021-05-01 11:38:00.679
ProfileScreen|1111   |2021-05-01 11:39:22.273|2021-05-01 11:38:00.679
WalletScreen |1111   |2021-05-01 11:40:00.329|2021-05-01 11:38:00.679
WalletScreen |1111   |2021-05-01 11:41:24.456|2021-05-01 11:38:00.679 <--- Delete
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:31:00.679|2021-05-03 11:31:00.679
WalletScreen |2222   |2021-05-03 11:35:22.273|2021-05-03 11:31:00.679
HomeScreen   |2222   |2021-05-03 11:37:00.329|2021-05-03 11:31:00.679
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:37:30.456|2021-05-03 11:31:00.679
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:38:00.679|2021-05-03 11:38:00.679
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:39:22.273|2021-05-03 11:38:00.679 <--- Delete
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:39:42.543|2021-05-03 11:38:00.679 <--- Delete
WalletScreen |2222   |2021-05-03 11:40:00.329|2021-05-03 11:38:00.679
ProfileScreen|2222   |2021-05-03 11:41:24.456|2021-05-03 11:38:00.679
```

Sorted by time event ascending, I'd like to delete any back-to-back (w/r/t time_event) repeat occurrences where the screen, user_id, and time_install are the same.

Comment: You can easily use `.drop_duplicates(subset =['event_name', 'user_id', time_install'], inplace=True)`

Comment: Is there a solution involving that approach that will keep preserve the earliest time_event row of the duplicated values while dropping the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the earliest time_event, you can first sort the df by time_event and then use 'keep=first' in drop_duplicates().

To sort, you can use `.sort_values(...)`

And to drop and keep the earliest, you can use

`.drop_duplicates(subset =['event_name', 'user_id', time_install'], inplace=True, keep='first')`